# Google Play Console отклонение платежей в 2023 в аккаунте российских разработчиков

Tags: google-play, in-app-purchases, android-billing

Возможно вопрос дурацкий, тк я немного отстала от жизни.
У меня уже пару лет существует аккаунт Google Play Console и я периодически (по выходным) обновляю приложения в надежде дополнительного заработка. До санкций было немного подписок. Подписки я подтверждаю (пользуюсь плагином InAppBilling для Xamarin), причем тесты всегда проходят нормально.
У меня была привязана карта Сбера, и в прошлом году в какой-то момент появилось сообщение от Google о проблеме с платежным счетом.
Поскольку тесты проходили нормально, а мне было совершенно некогда этим заниматься, я не придала этому значения.
В последнее время начала замечать плохие отзывы от пользователей и полное отсутствие подписок (их и раньше было несколько штук). Последний отзыв был вчера: "Premium still won't open".
Пару дней назад я все-таки оформила валютный (долларовый) счет Райфайзен и привязала его к Google Play Console, а сегодня заметила в разделе заказы несколько заказов со статусом отклонено за разные недели.
Вопросы:

1. Если счет получателя в Google Play Console находится под санкциями, может ли это быть причиной Отмены заказа?
2. Мгновенно или не сразу в консоли обновляется счет (мне счет виден и сообщений никаких не приходило)?
3. Я слышала, что российские разработчики больше не могут публиковать платные приложения в Google, так ли это?
4. Если кто-то находится в России, есть ли покупатели за рубежом, совершившие покупки в вашем приложении?

На моей странице нет сведений о нарушении правил или чего-то подобного.
Буду признательна за любую актуальную информацию.

Небольшое обновление: сегодня кто-то подписался и отменил подписку добровольно, но я всё равно немного нахожусь в замешательстве.

Comment: Попробуйте поискать ответ по чатам в телеграме, например `@android_ru` `@Android_Architecture`

Answer (score 0):

Сама отвечаю на свой вопрос, проблема разрешилась, когда купила новый телефон и обновился API android: я обнаружила своё приложение на новых телефонах в практически не рабочем состоянии. Я сразу же исправила проблему и после этого вновь появилось несколько подписок.
Со счётом Райффайзен все в порядке. Не знаю точно, смогу ли я вывести когда-нибудь деньги (поставила большой порог оплаты), но в консоли нет никаких проблем, причем, на вкладке управление заказами есть платежи от пользователей.
Не знаю, сколько это продлится, надо надеяться на лучшее).

Поправлю: платежи от пользователей за март, после этого оплата пробного периода (платежи с 0.0 значением). Точно не знаю, что это значит. Буду следить за проблемой.

Answer (score -1):

Из за неработающего `SWIFT` Российские разработчики больше не могут получать платежи от пользователей `Google Play`. Единственный магазин, который до сих пор принимает платежи - это `RuStore` от `VK` и `Минцифры РФ`. Это не реклама. Магазин появился после начала СВО как ответ Google Play. Там недавно добавили поддержку платежей.