Осталась ли сейчас возможность протестировать In-App purchases если аккаунт разработчика из РФ?
Приложение Flutter, настроил in-app purchases для Google Play, однако не получается сделать тестирование всего флоу покупок для подписки.
Пока вижу вариант - полностью мокать ответы сервиса, но хотелось бы использовать встроенные возможности.
Но всегда такой ответ

Остался ли какой-то способ тестировать покупки аккаунтом разработчика из РФ или нет?

https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1502354/261617
https://habr.com/ru/companies/surfstudio/articles/760748/

@MiT спасибо, ссылка годная, есть интересные моменты для меня, но не нашел варианта, как теперь протестировать...

и не найдете, я к этому и скинул...
